# Consolidate Log files and anonymize it

Tags: java, file, logging

I am very new in handling log files which brings me to this question on how and what is the process like to consolidate all the log file from different system like lets say router, firewall and home PC using windows 7? After that how to anonymize the data in the log file like masked my own name and even ip address (if possible)?

It would be great if the application to run this can be written in java. I just need some guide for this. Thank you very much! Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

From Google:
Try this (Java Based):
http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Consolidating-Logs-with-Logstash
 and This
http://www.spectorsoft.com/products/server-manager/event-log-management.asp